Playwright VS Code extension cannot find tests if config is dependent on environment variable
I am setting up playwright in hopes of having it run in 2 environments - an integration environment, and an e2e environment.  This should be controlled by env vars that are present when npx playwright test is run.  I saw a few articles that recommended adjusting your playwright.config.ts file based on the env var, so I have this:
import { PlaywrightTestConfig, defineConfig } from '@playwright/test'

export const baseConfig: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
  testDir: '.',
  outputDir: './test-results/',
  // more basic configs
}

const e2eConfig: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
  ...baseConfig,
  projects: [
    {
      name: 'E2E',
      testMatch: '**/e2e/**/*.spec.ts',
    },
  ],
  webServer: {
    command: 'NEXT_PUBLIC_PLAYWRIGHT_ENV=e2e npx next dev',
    port: 3112,
  },
}

const integrationConfig: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
  ...baseConfig,
  projects: [
    {
      name: 'setup',
      testMatch: '**/*.setup.ts',
    },
    {
      name: 'Integration Tests',
      dependencies: ['setup'],
      testMatch: '**/integration/**/*.spec.ts',
    },
  ],
  webServer: {
    command: 'cd ../ && npx next dev',
    port: 3112,
  },
}

export default defineConfig(process.env.PLAYWRIGHT_ENV === 'e2e' ? e2eConfig : integrationConfig)

Then I can run npx playwright test to run my integration tests, or PLAYWRIGHT_ENV=e2e npx playwright test to run my e2e tests.  This is working perfectly - depending on the env var, playwright chooses different projects, and runs a different webServer.command to go with it.
However, it appears that the VSCode extension for playwright uses this config to know what test files are playwright tests.  Because the "resting" vscode state does not have PLAYWRIGHT_ENV=e2e, it simply doesn't find any tests outside of the /integration folder.  My files:

What the playwright vscode extension finds based on the above config:

How can I adjust this?  How can I tell the VS Code extension to have a different criteria for where to find playwright tests than any of the projects in the config?  I want the extension to see all tests in all projects (basically all .(spec|setup).ts files within my playwright dir).
I have tried going into the options wthin the text explorer and changing the "select default profile", and adding the the e2e projects:

But this seems to have no effect on the tests listed in the test explorer, or on the test files themselves (no little play button next to each test).
Am I taking the wrong approach in trying to separate which tests run?  I read the playwright docs on how to Parameterize tests, but it didn't seem to address this issue.

How can I also get these test profiles?
I am not getting these options to select different project profiles like:

chromium
firefox
webkit
to run the test cases or debug them in VS Code.
Could you please help?

I am only getting one option:

playwright-debug(Default)

Attached image for reference: https://ibb.co/kBf3CxW

I'm not sure if this solves your exact situation but when I stumbled upon this question I found my answer in this GitHub issue: https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/27864 - We can set any generated env vars for Playwright in the VSCode settings json file.

This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question. - From Review

Try adding NODE_ENV=e2e in the .env file.
You might also have to tweak your launch.json, this is what I've got:
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Playwright Debug (Testnet)",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/playwright",
      "args": ["test", "--config=playwright.config.ts"],
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
      "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "test"
      },
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
      "sourceMaps": true
    }
  ]
}

